# RegEx cannot match when their are 0's using [^\000]*?

Tags: c#, regex

Good Day,

Is there any alternative in getting everything inside a tag using regex. here is my code:

```
   MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(chek, "<bib-parsed>([^\000]*?)</bib-parsed>");
```

here is the sample input:

```
   <bib-parsed>
   <cite>
   <pubinfo>
   <pub-year><i>1984</i></pub-year>
   <pub-place>Albuquerque</pub-place>
   <pub-name>Maxwell Museum of Anthropology and the University of New Mexico Press        </pub-name>
   </pubinfo>
   <bkinfo>
   <btl>The Galaz Ruin: A Prehistoric Mimbres Village in Southwestern New Mexico</btl>
   </bkinfo>
   </bib-parsed>
```

that sample above will be matched but when there are "0's inside the pubyear like "2001" the matching fails. any alternative for this? thanks

Comment: Noooooooooooooooooooooooooooo! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not,  obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454  I sense the pit opening...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears your input is valid XML. If this is the case, use the XML parsers in either `System.Xml` or `System.Xml.Linq`. They are **extremely** fast. For an input string containing multiple chunks like your example, using the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace objects:

```
var bibChunks = XDocument.Parse(yourXmlString)
                         .Descendants("bib-parsed")
                         .Select(e => e.Value);

foreach(string chunk in bibChunks) {
    // do stuff
}
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Hi.. im encountering a problem. this for well formed xml file? but im putting errors on it the compilation fails.

Comment: @ErickReyes Sorry I misspelled `Descendants`. I've corrected it now.